# Selenium, pandas writing same table to multiple CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use selenium and pandas to cycle through a 129 pages, grab a table from each and then output it to a csv with a unique filename. So far I've been able to almost all of that, but instead of generating a CSV and writing a table to it, it generates 129 CSVs and writes the same table to all of them. Here's my code:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

for ousd_name in ousd_list:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//option[@value="{ousd_name}"]').click()
    button = driver.find_element_by_id("submit1")
    button.click()
    sleep(2)
    table = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_grdDisc")
    tdf = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    for i in enumerate(filenames):
        tdf[1].to_csv(f'~/Desktop/{i}.csv', index=False)
    driver.get('https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/Expulsion/ExpSearchName.asp?TheYear=2018-19&cTopic=Expulsion&cLevel=School&cName=&cCounty=&cTimeFrame=S')
```

I know the issue is with the inner loop, but I cant figure out how to remove it and still generate the uniquely named CSVs. Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Does chaghing your main loop to `for i,ousd_name in enumerate(ousd_list):`, and removing your inner loop (also, remove indentation from `tdf[1].to_csv...` ) solve the issue?

Comment: It did, thank you!!